# Firebase said insecure rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firebase is mailing me 
That your entire database can be read and write by any user 
I have only enabled the email and password system.
My firebase rules are like below.

Here my code :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write;
    //:if request.auth.uid != null 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read up on it here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#access_for_any_authenticated_user

All you're doing right now is checking if they've logged in, if so, they can read and write. If that's what you want there's no problem.

Comment: When you have more reputation, you'll be able to leave comments. Your post is more of a comment than an answer to the question. When you post answers, take [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Make%20sure%20your%20answer%20provides,or%20simplifications%20in%20your%20answer.) into account, especially the highlighted parts.